# Adding AppToReference in BizTalk deployment project

Tags: azure-devops, biztalk

I am deploying BizTalk applications using BizTalk deployment project and azureDevOPS.

I need to add a reference to the another application. BTDF used to have "AppsToReference", how to achieve the same thing using BizTalk Deployment Project.

```
<ItemGroup>
 <AppsToReference Include=" Company.Application.SharedObjects"/>
 <AppsToReference Include="BizTalk EDI Application"/>
</ItemGroup>
```